# MSSQL: How to join only if its children not exist

Tags: sql-server

I want to left join but only if it does not have the specific child.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT "chatRoom"."id" as id, 
       "chatRoom"."name" as name, 
       "chatRoom"."type" as type, 
       "chatRoom"."description" as description, 
       "chatRoom"."thumbnail" as thumbnail, 
       "chatRoom"."status" as status, 
       chats.[unreadCount] as unreadCount
FROM "chat_room" "chatRoom" 
LEFT JOIN "chat_room_participant" "participants" ON "participants"."chatRoomId"="chatRoom"."id"  
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "chatRoom"."id" AS "chatRoomId", COUNT(readBy.id) AS "unreadCount"
    FROM "chat" "chat" 
    LEFT JOIN "chat_room" "chatRoom" ON "chatRoom"."id"="chat"."chatRoomId"  
    LEFT JOIN "chat_read_by_chat_room_participant" "chat_readBy" ON "chat_readBy"."chatId"="chat"."id" 
    LEFT JOIN "chat_room_participant" "readBy" ON "readBy"."id"="chat_readBy"."chatRoomParticipantId" 
    WHERE NOT(readBy.UserId IN ('ca774a5f-a04d-ec11-ae58-74d83e04f9d3'))
       OR "readBy"."id" IS NULL
    GROUP BY "chatRoom"."id"
) "chats" ON chats.chatRoomId = "chatRoom"."id" 
WHERE ('ALL' = 'ALL' OR "chatRoom"."status" = 'ALL')
  AND "chatRoom"."applicationId" = '4ac752e9-004c-ec11-ae53-74d83e04f9d3'
  AND "participants"."userId" = 'A97D66C4-014C-EC11-AE53-74D83E04F9D3'
ORDER BY "chatRoom"."lastUpdate" DESC
```

In this query, it returns the correct value only if the `readBy` is null or contains 1 entry which equals to the given `userId`.

So here I have the `userId`. I want to get all the `unread chats count` from each `chatRoom` that has the user as a participant.

The schema is like this:

```
chatRoom has many chats
chatRoom has many participants

chats has many to many `readBy` (participants)
```

So there is a column automatically created for the `many-to-many` relation:

```
column: chat_read_by_chat_room_participant
```

Contains:

```
|chatId|chatRoomParticipantId|
```

In my query above, the left join will get any `readBy` from another user:

```
WHERE NOT(readBy.UserId IN ('ca774a5f-a04d-ec11-ae58-74d83e04f9d3')) OR "readBy"."id" IS NULL GROUP BY "chatRoom"."id") "chats" ON chats.chatRoomId = "chatRoom"."id"
```

which I do not want. This will return the entry if the user already read the chat, but another users have read as well. I want to return the entry only if the user has not read the chat.

How can I do this?

---

### CREATION QUERY

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[chat](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [sentAt] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [filePath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [chatRoomId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [senderId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [userId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_9d0b2ba74336710fd31154738a5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_9d0b2ba74336710fd31154738a5]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_52af74c7484586ef4bdfd8e4dbb] FOREIGN KEY([userId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[chat_room_participant] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_52af74c7484586ef4bdfd8e4dbb]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_e49029a11d5d42ae8a5dd9919a2] FOREIGN KEY([chatRoomId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[chat_room] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_e49029a11d5d42ae8a5dd9919a2]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[chat_read_by_chat_room_participant](
    [chatId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [chatRoomParticipantId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_f3dd24628d4644dd6e79bcd03d1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [chatId] ASC,
    [chatRoomParticipantId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_read_by_chat_room_participant]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_011624ccd7e7b0281ef629f2930] FOREIGN KEY([chatId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[chat] ([id])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_read_by_chat_room_participant] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_011624ccd7e7b0281ef629f2930]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_read_by_chat_room_participant]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_2e33e3de9d7c91d426c09a24810] FOREIGN KEY([chatRoomParticipantId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[chat_room_participant] ([id])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_read_by_chat_room_participant] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_2e33e3de9d7c91d426c09a24810]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[chat_room](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [thumbnail] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [applicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [lastUpdate] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_8aa3a52cf74c96469f0ef9fbe3e] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_8aa3a52cf74c96469f0ef9fbe3e]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_2226638e6b7665ec0259d246b2b] FOREIGN KEY([applicationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[application] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_2226638e6b7665ec0259d246b2b]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[chat_room_participant](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [joinedAt] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [privilege] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [chatRoomId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [userId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_15913cf37a762fce4c8d6a32a42] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_ae9630d66f6c5d12afd1a991fec] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [chatRoomId] ASC,
    [userId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room_participant] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_15913cf37a762fce4c8d6a32a42]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room_participant]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_9f718459ea81b5130f81980ca08] FOREIGN KEY([userId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room_participant] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_9f718459ea81b5130f81980ca08]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room_participant]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_fb664f48a4ec615ec5cce90a25d] FOREIGN KEY([chatRoomId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[chat_room] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[chat_room_participant] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_fb664f48a4ec615ec5cce90a25d]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide information so that we can reproduce the problem. We need queries to create the relevant table(s) and to insert some sample data, in addition to the description of the expected result according to the sample data. Try to simplify the scenario as much as possible and focus on the source of the problem. If you can simplify the scenario to 2 tables for example instead of 40 then please do so. If not, then we need queries to create all 40 tables. You can use this place http://sqlfiddle.com/ to post the scenario or in the question itself.

Comment: I agree with @RonenAriely, as it is a complex query and somewhat badly indented on top of that. From what I can make of it you need to change `LEFT JOIN "chat_room_participant" "readBy"` into a `WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM "chat_room_participant" AS readBy WHERE "readBy"."id"="chat_readBy"."chatRoomParticipantId" AND readBy.UserId IN ('ca774a5f-a04d-ec11-ae58-74d83e04f9d3'))` I do not think you will be needing `OR "readBy"."id" IS NULL` condition.

Comment: I have indented it, could you post the combined query as answer? I could not make the syntax correct. Please help.

Comment: Please include example data for your tables and example results that your require, as per this advice : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: As per all the above comments. We cannot help you without source data or example data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery.

Don't be tempted to just use `LEFT JOIN` `IS NULL` syntax, it is generally less efficient, as it hides from the optimizer that you are doing an anti-join. Occasionally it can be useful though.

Further notes:

- Don't quote column and table names unless you have to. And generally avoid names that need quoting.
- Don't alias columns that don't need aliasing.
- Choose *short* meaningful table aliases.
- Basic formatting and good use of whitespace helps readability
- Your `LEFT JOIN chat_room_participant` logically becomes an `INNER JOIN` because of the `WHERE`.
- You don't need to re-join `chat_room` in the grouped subquery, you can just group by the join column.
- You may want to use a grouped `OUTER APPLY` instead of that subquery. It is unlikely to get a different query plan, but it can be easier to read.
- `COUNT(SomeNotNullValue)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`
- `('ALL' = 'ALL' OR cr.status = 'ALL')` only makes sense if `cr.Status` is nullable, otherwise you would just use `cr.status = 'ALL'`. Even if it is nullable, you may as well use `(cr.Status IS NULL OR cr.status = 'ALL')`

```sql
SELECT
  cr.id,
  cr.name, 
  cr.type, 
  cr.description, 
  cr.thumbnail, 
  cr.status, 
  c.unreadCount
FROM chat_room cr
JOIN chat_room_participant p ON p.chatRoomId = cr.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      c.chatRoomId AS chatRoomId,
      COUNT(*) AS unreadCount
    FROM chat c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM chat_read_by_chat_room_participant chat_readBy
        JOIN chat_room_participant readBy ON readBy.id = chat_readBy.chatRoomParticipantId
        WHERE chat_readBy.chatId = c.id
          AND readBy.UserId IN ('ca774a5f-a04d-ec11-ae58-74d83e04f9d3')
    )
    GROUP BY c.chatRoomId
) c ON c.chatRoomId = cr.id
WHERE (cr.Status IS NULL OR cr.status = 'ALL')
  AND cr.applicationId = '4ac752e9-004c-ec11-ae53-74d83e04f9d3'
  AND p.userId = 'A97D66C4-014C-EC11-AE53-74D83E04F9D3'
ORDER BY
  cr.lastUpdate DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working now. There should be some changes in the code like `) c ON c.chatRoomId = cr.id` should be `) ch on ch.chatRoomId = cr.id`. That `('ALL' = 'ALL` is just for demonstration, in my real query this will be changed into variables `@1 = 'ALL'`. Thank you for the guide.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that what you want is an anti-semi join. That is, a join to demonstrate that a row does not exist.

The two typical methods are...

```
  main_table    AS m
LEFT JOIN
  other_table   AS o
    ON  o.m_id = m.id
    AND o.user = 'xyz'
WHERE
  o.id IS NULL
```

Or...

```
  main_table   AS m
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM other_table   AS o
     WHERE o.m_id = m.id
       AND o.user = 'xyz'
  )
```

Exactly how to apply this to your example is unclear as you have cluttered your question with too many other details. (It is not a Minimal Verifiable Example.)

Comment: I am sorry for my messy question, you give me a great info for this, thank you.